# Laravel 5.6 & Algolia search return empty result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, algolia

I'm using **Algolia** on **Laravel 5.6**. I follow the tutorial on **Laravel** doc.

```
$searches = Application::search($query)->get();
```

> Collection {#243 ▼   #items: [] }

When I search an application, the result return me 0 item.

I type this command:

```
php artisan scout:import "App\Models\Application"
```

to send items on Algolia, and they are present on Algolia dashboard, I can see it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;

class Application extends Model
{
    use Searchable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'title',
        'slug',
        'short_description',
        'long_description',
        'state',
    ];

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function searchableAs()
    {
        return 'applications';
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getScoutKey()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have customized the Scout Key but not the Scout Key Name.

Currently, Scout will try to build a collection matching IDs against titles. Once you defined the `getScoutKeyName` method (which should return something like a string `title`). It should be working

Answer (score -2):

You currently have a namespace of `App\Models`. Have you tried updating your search call to mirror this namespace?:

```
$searches = App\Models\Application::search($query)->get();
```

Comment: I have the same problem... If I use the method raw(), I have data, but they are not typed by the model ...

Comment: @pirmax did you solve the problem?